# Syntax error when joining tables in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have this basic join that's not working in Teradata. I ran the individual tables separately, and was working fine. So I think joining is the problem.

```
(
select age, sex, sum(members) as Membership
from tablem
group by 1,2
) m

left join

(
select age, sex
from tablec
) c

on m.age = c.age  and  m.sex = c.sex
```

Comment: Hint:  A SQL query starts with `SELECT`, not usually with `(`.

Comment: oooo let me try! thanks !

Comment: @GordonLinoff, actually the `JOIN` without `SELECT` wasn't removed from the SQL standard until 2003! This query is valid SQL-99 syntax, except the GROUP BY ordinal position part.

Comment: This query is missing both the `SELECT` and the `FROM` clause. Stick `SELECT * FROM` at the beginning of this and rerun.

Comment: thank you for all the comments !